# $A = \{1 , 2 , 3\}$ and $R = \{(1 , 1) , (2 , 2) \}$. Can anyone please tell me how would I explain that the relation $R$ is transitive?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Let $A$ be a set. $A = \{1 , 2 , 3\}$.

$R = \{(1 , 1) , (2 , 2) \}$. Can anyone please tell me how would I explain that the relation $R$  is transitive ?

**My Attempt:** I taught my student first what is non-transitive. If  we get two elements such that $(a , b) , (b , c)$ but the $a$ is not related to $c$ , then we call the relation Non-transitive. If a relation is not a Non-transitive , we call that a Transitive Relation.

So the given relation is not a non-transitive. Since there is no such case.

Can anyone give me a better way to help 10+2 level students understand what  a transitive relation is?

Answer (score 2):

The answer lies in the truth value of conditional statement $p\implies q$.

A conditional $p\implies q$ is true (T) whenever the *hypothesis* $p$ is false (F) irrespective of the truth value of $q$. Mathematicians call it *vacuous* *truth*.
The definition of transitive i.e.

> If $(a,b)\in R$ and $(b,c)\in R$ then $(a,c)\in R$.

is a conditional $p\implies q$ where

$p$: $(a,b)\in R, (b,c)\in R$

$q$: $(a,c)\in R$

So whenever you find that the hypothesis $p$ is false, the relation $R$ becomes transitive.

Comment: I know this. But I can not make it easy enough to help my 10+2 students understand.

Answer (score 1):

For this relation $R$, we have $a\mathrel Rb$ when and only when $a=b$ and $a,b\in\{1,2\}$. So, if $a\mathrel Rb$ and $b\mathrel Rc$, we have that $a=b$, that $b=c$, and that $a,b,c\in\{1,2\}$. So, $a=c$ and $a,c\in\{1,2\}$, which means that $a\mathrel Rc$.

Of course, by the same argument, if $A$ is *any* set and if $R\subset\{(a,a)\mid a\in A\}$, then $R$ is transitive.

Comment: I want to show that the given relation a transitive from a general concept by which I can identify any relation a transitive or non-transitive.

Comment: If you want to prove that a relation is *not* transitive, just find $a,b,c\in A$ such that $a\mathrel Rb$, $b\mathrel Rc$, and $a\not\mathrel Rc$.

Comment: @sani The general concept is to assume $(a,b),(b,c) \in R$ and show $(a,c) \in R.$ This is as general as it gets.

Comment: But by the definition how would you show that the given R is transitive.

Comment: This is exactly by definition. Your definition of non-transitive is that if there exists $(a,b),(b,c)\in R$ such that $(a,c) \notin R,$ then $R$ is non-transitive. The negation of this is: $R$ is transitive if **for every** $(a,b),(b,c) \in R$ we have $(a,c) \in R.$

Comment: If $a\mathrel Rb$ and $b\mathrel c$, then either $a=b=1$ or $a=b=2$; furthermore $b=c=1$ or $b=c=2$. So, either $a=b=c=1$ or $a=b=c=2$ and in either case you have $a\mathrel Rc$.

Comment: Can you please tell me what happens  If the relation were R= $\{ (1 , 2)  \}? @SahibaArora

Comment: By your argument  we can solve this specific problem. But I want a argument by which I can identify any such relation as transitive or non-transitive.@JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: That's how thing work here. You post specific problems and, usually, you get a way of solving *that* specific problem. I don't see how is it that you post a specific problem about transitive relations and then you expect a way of solving any problem about transitive relations.

Comment: @sani Again apply the same argument. If $R=\{(1,2)\}$ and you assume $(a,b),(b,c)\in R,$ then $a=1$ and $b=2.$ Also $b=1$ and $c=2$, which is a contradiction. So $R$ is vacously transitive. (If you have difficulty seeing this, draw the truth table for $P\implies Q$)

Answer (score 0):

Let $(a,b), (b,c) \in R.$ Since $A$ consists consists of two elements, therefore either $c=a$ or $c=b.$

**Case 1: $c=a$** Then you want to show $(a,a)\in R$ which is true.

**Case 2: $c=b$** Then you want to show $(a,b) \in R$ which is true.

Comment: If $A$ contains $a , b , c$ , then?

Comment: @sani Then depends on what $R$ is.

Comment: What about the given $R$?

Comment: @sani For the given $R.$ If $(a,b) \in R$ and $(b,c) \in R,$ then $b=a$ and $c=b$ which implies $a=c.$ Then clearly $(a,c)=(a,a) \in R.$

Answer (score 0):

Definition of transitivity of a relation $\rho$ on a set $S$ is, if $a\rho b$ and $b\rho c$ then $a\rho c$ for any $a,b,c\in S$.

Now, here $\rho =\{(1,1),(2,2)\}$. So for the assumption $a\rho b$ and $b\rho c$, $b=1$ or $2$.

If $b=1$ then $a=c=1$, which gives $a\rho c$.

Next, If $b=2$ then $a=c=2$, which also gives $a\rho c$.

Hence the condition gets satisfied. Thus, the relation $\rho$ is transitive.